# SQLite index benchmark

Tags: sql, sqlite

### The problem

I have the following schema in an SQLite DB:

table: Dispatches

- rowid: primary key
- identifier: string
- route: integer
- slot: integer

The most common query is:

```
SELECT * FROM dispatches WHERE route = 1 ORDER BY slot ASC
```

While attempting to optimize the indexes used I tried 4 approaches:

1. No indexes
2. Index by route
3. Composite index by route and slot
4. Separate index by route and slot

For each case I'm inserting `n=10000` records. The route is either 0 or 1 (random) and the slot is a random number between 0 and n-1.

Shockingly, when results are ran and the approaches are ordered by speed, I'm getting the same order. In other words, the **fastest one is the table with no indexes**.

### SQLite details

Here are the `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` outputs (edited):

1. `SCAN TABLE dispatches USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY`
2. `SEARCH TABLE dispatch_index_routes USING INDEX index_dispatch_index_routes_on_route (route=?) USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY`
3. `SEARCH TABLE dispatch_index_composites USING INDEX index_dispatch_index_composites_on_route_and_slot (route=?)`
4. `SEARCH TABLE dispatch_index_separates USING INDEX index_dispatch_index_separates_on_route (route=?) USE TEMP B-TREE FOR ORDER BY`

### Test script

This was all implemented using ActiveRecord (I'm actually optimizing for an Android app, but I figured that it shouldn't be that much different when benchmarking in a PC):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'active_record'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'benchmark'

db_name = 'test_db'
# Change the following to reflect your database settings
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter:  'sqlite3', # or 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3'
  host:     'localhost',
  database: db_name
)

#ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS #{db_name}")
#ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("USE test_db")

class Dispatch < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class DispatchIndexRoute < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class DispatchIndexComposite < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class DispatchIndexSeparate < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class DispatchIndexCovering < ActiveRecord::Base

end

# Define a minimal database schema
unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:dispatches)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :dispatches, force: true do |t|
    t.string  :identifier
    t.integer :route
    t.integer :slot
  end
end

unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:dispatch_index_routes)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :dispatch_index_routes, force: true do |t|
    t.string  :identifier
    t.integer :route, index: true
    t.integer :slot
  end
end

unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:dispatch_index_separates)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :dispatch_index_separates, force: true do |t|
    t.string  :identifier
    t.integer :route, index: true
    t.integer :slot, index: true
  end
end

unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:dispatch_index_composites)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :dispatch_index_composites, force: true do |t|
    t.string  :identifier
    t.integer :route
    t.integer :slot

    t.index [:route, :slot]
  end
end

unless ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?(:dispatch_index_coverings)
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.create_table :dispatch_index_coverings, force: true do |t|
    t.string  :identifier
    t.integer :route
    t.integer :slot

    t.index [:route, :slot, :id, :identifier], name: 'dispatch_covering_idx'
  end
end

classes = [Dispatch, DispatchIndexRoute, DispatchIndexComposite, DispatchIndexSeparate, DispatchIndexCovering]

classes.each do |c|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM #{c.table_name};")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("VACUUM;")
end

puts "Creating items"
n = 10000
n.times.each do |i|
  name = SecureRandom.hex
  route = Random.rand(2)
  slot = Random.rand(n)
  classes.each do |c|
    c.new(identifier: name, route: route, slot: slot).save!
  end
  if i > 0 && (i % (n / 10)) == 0
    print i
  end
end
puts "Done creating items"

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("ANALYZE;")

iterations = 1
classes.each do |c|
  table_name = c.table_name
  puts "Results for #{table_name}"
  query = "SELECT * FROM #{table_name} WHERE route = 1 ORDER BY slot ASC"
  # puts ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN #{query}")
  Benchmark.bm do |bm|
    bm.report do
      iterations.times do
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(query)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And the output:

```
Creating items
100020003000400050006000700080009000Done creating items
Results for dispatches
       user     system      total        real
   0.100000   0.010000   0.110000 (  0.108072)
Results for dispatch_index_routes
       user     system      total        real
   0.120000   0.000000   0.120000 (  0.123919)
Results for dispatch_index_composites
       user     system      total        real
   0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.138045)
Results for dispatch_index_separates
       user     system      total        real
   0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.138734)
```

Versions:

```
$ sqlite3 --version
3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57 c8ade949d4a2eb3bba4702a4a0e17b405e9b6ace
$ ruby --version
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13 revision 48405) [x86_64-darwin14.0]
```

### Question

I don't understand the results. Shouldn't the composite index be the fastest? I see that the first one is using `SCAN` instead o `SEARCH`, but still. How can it be faster?

### Edit

At first glance, adding a covering index does not speed up the queries:

```
Results for dispatches
       user     system      total        real
   0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.104801)
Results for dispatch_index_routes
       user     system      total        real
   0.130000   0.010000   0.140000 (  0.133568)
Results for dispatch_index_composites
       user     system      total        real
   0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.143194)
Results for dispatch_index_separates
       user     system      total        real
   0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.144586)
Results for dispatch_index_coverings
       user     system      total        real
   0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.137730)
```

It does get better after running `ANALYZE` as @CL. suggested:

```
Results for dispatches
       user     system      total        real
   0.090000   0.000000   0.090000 (  0.098393)
Results for dispatch_index_routes
       user     system      total        real
   0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.137758)
Results for dispatch_index_composites
       user     system      total        real
   0.130000   0.010000   0.140000 (  0.134864)
Results for dispatch_index_separates
       user     system      total        real
   0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.142418)
Results for dispatch_index_coverings
       user     system      total        real
   0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.098227)
```

Trying with a less randomized `route` value doesn't help much, since only some options get a speedup:

```
Results for dispatches
       user     system      total        real
   0.220000   0.010000   0.230000 (  0.228870)
Results for dispatch_index_routes
       user     system      total        real
   0.170000   0.020000   0.190000 (  0.190722)
Results for dispatch_index_composites
       user     system      total        real
   0.230000   0.000000   0.230000 (  0.242936)
Results for dispatch_index_separates
       user     system      total        real
   0.240000   0.010000   0.250000 (  0.253333)
Results for dispatch_index_coverings
       user     system      total        real
   0.190000   0.000000   0.190000 (  0.205272)
```

Comment: Just running [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) should help.

Answer (score 0):

> The route is either 0 or 1 (random)

I think this is the key to why the performance is essentially the same -- or even that the indexes make things worse.  If I understand correctly, you need to read every other record.

A full-table scan reads the records and discards the unneeded ones. An index scan goes into the index and reads only the ones you need.  However, it is then bouncing between data pages for each record.  My guess is that the overhead of reading the record in the index and the non-locality reference is about the same as reading an additional row in the table.

So, an index for filtering is not going to help (actually, a *clustered* index might help).

That leaves the sorting.  I'm not sure how the SQLite optimizer works.  However, the following index might show some gain:  `(route, slot, rowid, identifier)`.  This is a covering index, so there is no need to go to the data pages when processing the query.

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. I'll try the covering index and get back to you.

Comment: Here's a great article talking about this concept, which is called selectivity - [Selectivity in SQL Databases](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/selectivity-in-sql-databases/).